# Pulseaudio/X permission other user/SSH

Tags: linux, x11, pulseaudio, authorization

My user user1 is running a graphical X session with pulse configured per-user.

I need to run a graphical program that uses audio with user2.

- If I do `su user2; program` program doesn't start and I get no audio neither video
- If I do `gksu -u user2 program` the video is working, but I get no audio.

Why there are these problems? What is the right way to start a pulse application that outputs sound on the pulse of my user? What the right way to start an X/audio application from another session(for example an SSH shell)?

Comment: I've the same issue and still looking for a solution, did you find any?

Answer (score 2):

As 'user2'

```
echo "default-server = unix:/tmp/pulse-socket" >> ~user2/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

As 'user1'

```
echo "load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/pulse-socket" >> ~user1/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

then restart the server:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Works great with 'su' (or 'su -l'). I haven't tried with 'ssh' but it should work the same.

You can also limit the access by using options with module-native-protocol-unix, as in:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-group=othergroup socket=/tmp/pulse-socket
```

**Source:**

See the Arch Wiki paragraph
[**Allowing multiple users to use PulseAudio at the same time**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Allowing_multiple_users_to_use_PulseAudio_at_the_same_time)

Comment: Are you sure about the paths you're referencing for the config files? For example, shouldn't *~user2/.config/pulse/client.conf* (which expands to */home/user2user2/.config/pulse/client.conf*) be *~/.config/pulse/client.conf*?

Comment: Yup. I'm pretty sure. It's been like that for longer than I can remember.

Comment: I would bet that all shells do the same too. That is '~', if used without extra characters, will be substituted by the content of the HOME env. variable. If used with extra characters, those extra characters will be treated as a potential username. If the username is an actual user, then '~username' will be substituted with username home directory path, something like '~foo' -> 'home/foo'.

So, yeah, the paths I gave are correct. Of course 'user1' and 'user2' are merely examples.

Comment: if you type 'man bash' search for 'tilde-prefix'